# GWT: how to access/change HTML Panel's value

Tags: java, gwt

I have an HTML Panel , where i am saving some text and then i want to access some specific HTML Panel's node and change its attribute ,

This is what i am doing

```
      HTMLPanel htmlText;
      htmlText.setInnerHTML(result.getText());
      Node x  = htmlText.getChild(1);
```

I am getting this javascriptObject$    as the value of x   (If i see in in Debug)

```
     <span class="my-wrapper"><span class="myText">testing text</span><span class="myNumber"> (2) </span></span>
```

What i need is to get only this text  "testing text" and change its color.

is it possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may want to use [GWTQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) for this type of thing.

```
HTMLPanel htmlText;
htmlText.setInnerHTML(result.getText());
//Node x  = htmlText.getChild(1);

String value = $(".myText", htmlText).text();
```